# Python: Add Values and Remove Entry for Tuple Permutations in a Dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, permutation

I have a dictionary where the key is a tuple. Some of these tuples are permutations of each other (e.g. `(1, 2)` vs `(2, 1)`). I want to add the value of one permutation to the other, and then get rid of the second permutation.

```
d = {(1, 3): 14, (1, 4): 13, (1, 2): 10, (11, 11): 19, (3, 1): 50, (4, 1): 5, ...}
```

should be

```
{(1, 3): 64, (1, 4): 18, (1, 2): 10, (11, 11): 19, ...}
```

I thought about sorting them and then doing something based on position in the dictionary, but this is not very easy to scale up. Input is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @wim suggested, you should probably use a `frozenset`, then you can use `collections.Counter` and `sum` to cumulate the values into a new dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {(1, 3): 14, (1, 4): 13, (1, 2): 10, (11, 11): 19, (3, 1): 50, (4, 1): 5}

r = sum((Counter({frozenset(k): v}) for k, v in d.items()), Counter())
print(r)
# Counter({frozenset({1, 3}): 64, frozenset({11}): 19, frozenset({1, 4}): 18, frozenset({1, 2}): 10})
```

You may turn the `Counter` object into a vanilla dict and the keys back to tuples if you so wish using a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) for the dict key instead of a tuple.  Then you can just add them as you go along, without worrying about ordering.